How to setup griddb-python on JupyterLab
I'm trying to install griddb-python on my JupyterLab notebook and running into error. I'm trying to connect to my griddb running in Docker as part of WSL/Ubuntu.
%pip install griddb-python
Collecting griddb-python
  Using cached griddb_python-0.7.6.tar.gz (52 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: griddb-python
  Building wheel for griddb-python (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for griddb-python (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for griddb-python
Failed to build griddb-python
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
      C:\Users\lukes\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:111: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: bdist_wheel.universal is deprecated
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              With Python 2.7 end-of-life, support for building universal wheels
              (i.e., wheels that support both Python 2 and Python 3)
              is being obviated.
              Please discontinue using this option, or if you still need it,
              file an issue with pypa/setuptools describing your use case.
      
              By 2025-Aug-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        self.finalize_options()
      running build
      running build_ext
      building '_griddb_python' extension
      swigging src/griddb.i to src/griddb_wrap.cpp
      swig.exe -python -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -c++ -outdir . -Isrc -o src/griddb_wrap.cpp src/griddb.i
      error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for griddb-python
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (griddb-python)

After some research, I think it related to some library. I updated numpy, pandas, and installed swig and restarted but I'm still getting the same error.
I'm using the following:
Windows 10 with Docker v4.36.0 integrated with WSL/Ubuntu
Anaconda 24.11.1
Python 3.9.21
SWIG 4.2.0
NumPy 1.26.4
Pandas 2.2.2
Any idea how I can resolve the error?
